# Field calculated from Foreign Keys, need to save twice?

Tags: python, django

I've a model like this:

```
class IPv4Pool(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    available_ips = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IPv4Pool, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.available_ips = 0
        for ip_range in self.ip_range_set.all():
            print str(ip_range)
            self.available_ips += len(ip_range)
```

as the self.available_ips is calculated from the ForeignKeys, and they are not assigned until the model is saved (at least this is what I think) the value for available_ips is only calculated after a second save.

What's the elegant pythonic way of doing this? Should I call save a second time after calculating the value?

Comment: I can't see how you can have any ip_range objects pointing at this when you first save, anyway. Someone would have to add them by pointing their FKs at this object, which can only happen well after it's been saved, surely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem with current approach**

You shouldn't really have database field that is calculated like that.  It can lead to data inconsistency issues in your database.

Take this scenario for example:

```
>>> pool = IPv4Pool.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> pool.available_ips
2
>>> range = IPRange()
>>> range.pool = poll
>>> range.save()
>>> pool.available_ips
2
```

Nobody has updated `available_ips`, so now the data in the database is inconsistent. There are 3 `IPRange` rows pointing at that `pool`, but the `pool` only thinks there are 2.

**A better way**

You should update your models to the following:

```
class IPv4Pool(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class IPRange(models.Model):
    pool = models.ForeignKey(IPv4Pool, related_name='ip_ranges')
    ...

class Subscriber(models.Model):
    pool = models.ForeignKey(IPv4Pool, related_name='subscribers')
    ...
```

And use the features of the Django ORM to query this data:

```
pool.ip_ranges.count()
```

If you really want an `available_ips` attribute on your `IPv4Pool` class, use this:

```
class IPv4Pool(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @property
    def available_ips(self):
        return self.ip_ranges.count()
```

But to me there doesn't seem to be much benefit to that really.

**Handling complex queries**

Based on your comments to this answer, you are wanting to be able to filter `IPv4Pool` objects based on the counts of the related objects. You also want to be able to use [`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.F) objects in those queries, which is sensible.  This can be achieved using the Django [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/) API.

As an example, let's say you want this query:

- give me all the pools where the number of subscribers is less than the number of ranges

You'd need this particular incantation:

```
IPv4Pool.objects.annotate(available_ips=Count('ip_ranges'),
                          num_subscribers=Count('subscribers'),
                 ).filter(num_subscribers__lt=F('available_ips'))
```

If that seems overly verbose to type every time, you could add a [custom model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets), which automatically adds these annotations to each query:

```
class AnnotatedIPv4PoolManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        query = super(AnnotatedIPv4PoolManager, self).get_queryset()
        return query.annotate(available_ips=Count('ip_ranges'),
                              num_subscribers=Count('subscribers'),
                              )

class IPv4Pool(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    annotated = AnnotatedIPv4PoolManager()
```

Which you would then use like this to the same effect as above:

```
IPv4Pool.annotated.filter(num_subscribers__lt=F('available_ips'))
```

Comment: thanks, using the @property worked great. And as I will not have many FKs, calculating them in realtime instead of storing on DB is enough.

Comment: No matter how many FKs you've got, it's never correct to store that kind of info. It's the database's job to do that work for you. The solution to performance issues is to create a database index of that key, then the database doesn't have to actually go through all the data checking for a value, it just looks it up in the index. The difference between that and your method of doing the same, is that the database will never be inconsistent.

Comment: One problem I've found following this approach is that fields defined as @property are not allowed on F expressions: num_subscribers__lt=F('available_networks'). Any workaround for this?

Comment: Do you also have a `Subscriber` model, with an FK to `IPv4Pool`?

Comment: Yes, there is a `Subscriber`, with FK to `IPv4` & `IPv6` Pools, and the IPv4 pool has FK to `IP_Ranges`.